# How to get submatrices from a matrix?

Tags: java, matrix

I have an assignment where I have to open a text file (matrix.txt) and get two matrices from the file, matrix A and matrix B. Once I get those matrices I have to turn them into four equal or close to equal sized matrices.

ex.

```
A = [{A_00, A_01}, {A_10, A_11}]
```

I must do this with both matrices that I get from the text file and then add them together to get a new matrix C.

ex.

```
C = [{A_00+B_00, A_01+B_01}, {A_10+B_10, A_11+B_11}]
```

I am able to get the matrices from the text file correctly, but now that I have my matrix A and B I do not know how to turn them into their respective submatrices. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated! If needed I can provide the assignment document to help provide more clarification.

An example of the text file given

```
4 7
2 3 1 2 5 1 2
3 1 2 2 2 4 4
1 2 3 2 7 2 1
3 6 1 5 1 3 5
6 5 4 1 4 3 1
3 3 2 2 1 1 2
7 5 4 3 2 5 3
2 1 8 4 8 4 4
```

Here is my code so far

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    
    public class MatrixThread {
            
        public static Scanner scan;
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            
                if(args.length == 0){
                System.out.println("File name not specified");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            
            try{
                File matrix = new File(args[0]);
                scan = new Scanner(matrix);
            } catch (IOException ioException) {
                System.err.println("Cannot open file.");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            ThreadOperation Operation = new ThreadOperation();
            Operation.executeOperation();
            
        }
    }
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class ThreadOperation extends MatrixThread {
    
    
    void executeOperation(){
        
        int N = scan.nextInt();
        int M = scan.nextInt();
            
        int A[][] = new int [N][M];
        int B[][] = new int [N][M];
    
        for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < M; ++j)
            {               
                if(scan.hasNextInt())
                {
                    A[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
                }
            }
        }
                
        for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < M; ++j)
            {               
                if(scan.hasNextInt())
                {
                    B[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
                }
            }
        }
        
        /*int C[][] = new int [N][M];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < M; j++){
                C[i][j] = A[i][j] + B[i][j];
                System.out.print(C[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.print("\r\n");*/
        }
    }
}
```

The desired output with the example file given would be:

```
     N = 4, M = 7
    
    Matrix A:
    2 3 1 2 5 1 2
    3 1 2 2 2 4 4
    1 2 3 2 7 2 1
    3 6 1 5 1 3 5 
    
    Matrix B:
    6 5 4 1 4 3 1 
    3 3 2 2 1 1 2 
    7 5 4 3 2 5 3 
    2 1 8 4 8 4 4
    
    Submatrix A_00:
    2 3 1 2
    3 1 2 2 
    Submatrix A_01:
    5 1 2
    2 4 4
    Submatrix A_10:
    1 2 3 2
    3 6 1 5
    Submatrix A_11:
    7 2 1
    1 3 5
    Submatrix B_00:
    6 5 4 1 
    3 3 2 2
    Submatrix B_01:
    4 3 1
    1 1 2
    Submatrix B_10:
    7 5 4 3 
    2 1 8 4
    Submatrix B_11:
    2 5 3
    8 4 4
    Submatrix C_00:
    8 8 5 3
    6 4 4 4 
    Submatrix C_01:
    9 4 3
    3 5 6 
    Submatrix C_10:
    8 7 7 5
    5 7 9 9
    Submatrix C_11:
    9 7 4 
    9 7 9

    Matrix C:
    8 8 5 3 9 4 3
    6 4 4 4 3 5 6
    8 7 7 5 9 7 4 
    5 7 9 9 9 7 9
```

Comment: I guess you don't have to do anything with A and B. Just only use the relevant part to calculate C.

Comment: The reason the commented part towards the end is not sufficient is because the assignment states that I have to divide the matrices into submatrices before I do the addition. The reason for this has me confused as well because like you stated the end should be sufficient enough. I will try to provide a good sample output here shortly

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
A00[][] = new int[N / 2][M / 2];
for (int i = 0; i < A00.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < A00[0].length; j++) {
        A00[i][j] = A[i][j];
    }
}

A01[][] = new int[N / 2][M - M/2];
for (int i = 0; i < A01.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < A01[0].length; j++) {
        A01[i][j] = A[i][M/2 + j];
    }
}
```

and do similar computations to get other submatrices.

Comment: Where would it fail? E.g. 5/2 = 2, 5-5/2=3